# How to do the jolt transformation for a list of json object

Tags: jolt

My Input is as below:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "327703",
    "Caption": "TEST>> photo 1",
    "Url": "http://bob.com/0001/327703/photo.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Id": "327704",
    "Caption": "TEST>> photo 2",
    "Url": "http://bob.com/0001/327704/photo.jpg"
  }
]
```

and the expected output is:

```json
{
    "327703": {
        "Caption": "TEST>> photo 1",
        "Url": "http://bob.com/0001/327703/photo.jpg"
    },
    "327704": {
        "Caption": "TEST>> photo 2",
        "Url": "http://bob.com/0001/327704/photo.jpg"
    }
}
```

Please help me this and please suggest a good tutorial to get the fundamentals of all wildcards in JOLT.

Answer (score 1):

This spec should work for you:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Id": null,
        "*": "@(1,Id).&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The resources that I've learned from are:

- https://jolt-demo.appspot.com - demo app with a couple of examples to play with
- https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt - the Jolt repo where you can find the implementation and the description of each transformation (in javadocs)
- StackOverflow :D

For this transformation have a look at [shift docs](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java) - especially:

- [`*` wildcard](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L146) docs
- [`@` wildcard](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L300). and [advanced `@` wildcard](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L324) docs
- [`&` wildcard](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L184) docs

---

Explanation of the above:

1. Outermost part matches every element of our list:

```json
"*" : { 
... 
}
```

2. The inside of the object:

```json
    "Id": null
```

Says

> For every `"Id"` key inside each element of the array (found during the 1st step): put  the value under the `null` key - remove the `"Id"` key and its value from the element of the list.

The second part:

```json
   "*": "@(1,Id).&"
```

Says:

> match all other keys within the list element and place them under the `"@(1,Id).&"` key.

What does `"@(1,Id).&"` mean? Looking at the docs linked above we can translate (paraphrasing the advanced `@` wildcard docs):

- `"@(1,Id)"` to:

> Go up one level from here and look for the value under the `"Id"` key. Use the value at that key (as our new key).

`"@(1,Id)"` becomes `"327703"` for the `0th` element of the array.

... ok but we do not want to place values from `"Caption"` and `"Url"` right under the `"327703"`. If we did, our object would look like this:

```json
{
  "327703" : [ "TEST>> photo 1", "http://bob.com/0001/327703/photo.jpg" ],
  ...
}
```

We want to place `"Caption"` under the `"Caption"`. Here the `&` wildcard comes in handy (look at the docs linked above). When `"*"` wildcard matches:

- `"Candy"`- the value under the `"Candy"` key will be placed in the output's `"327703"."Candy"` key
- `"Url"`- the value under the `"Url"` key will be placed in the output's `"327703"."Url"` key

etc.